# Google Play console: Quality -> Reviews: Device names are slightly different, is an API to map?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, review

There are manufacturers' names and carriers' names which are listed differently, as evident by clicking on the Device in Reviews.

eg. On the main Reviews page, the Device: shows Huawei HUAWEI nova 5T, and when clicked, it shows both the original name and a shortened HWYAL. The downloaded CSV report shows HWYAL. I need to map it back to the original proper Device: name. Preferably to more useful information like Operating system, etc., which are not reflected on the Reviews report.

Any advice would be appreciated :)[How after clicking on Device: it shows 2 different code names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njhZp.png)

Comment: There is no API for that.  You'd either need to create the database yourself, or find someone else who's done so.